# mysql busquedas evitando ñ y acentos

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer consultas mysql que no importe que se usen acentos en los registros guardados.

el manual de mysql habla sobre las COLLATES ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci = k;
```

pero PHPMyAdmin me da error en ese tipo de consultas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso Mysql 5.7

Comment: Prueba con `COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE '%gomez%'`

Comment: ¿Removiste las comillas?